# Change navbar type (Horizontal, vertical and collapsed) depending on the resolution with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Is it possible to change the `navbar` type depending on the resolution with Bootstrap?

something like this:

```
PC/laptop - Vertical

Tablet - Horizontal

SmartPhone - Collapsed
```

Comment: What have you researched or attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries
[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)